# sed find and replace in file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a json file with a line as below,

```
"image": "docker.abc.com/abc-pr0000abc:ABCCoreUI-46",
```

Can some one help me with sed command that can replace above as below,

```
"image": "docker.abc.com/abc-pr0000abc:ABCCoreUI-47",
```

Also I would like to wild card 46, something like ABCCoreUI-*

I tried `sed s/ABCCoreUI-4*/ABCCoreUI-47/ file.json`

Output become,

```
"image": "docker.abc.com/abc-pr0000abc:ABCCoreUI-4742",
```

Thanks

Comment: Are the `xxx`s static obfuscated strings, or are they different in every instance you wish to alter?

Comment: thats correct. xxx is always static.

Comment: in regex (used by sed) `*` means any 0 or more of previous atom (character or bracketed thing). You are mixing it up with globs. Just replacing your `*` with `.*` should do it. ( `.` means any character `[.]` or `\.` means `.` ).

Answer (score 1):

> Also I would like to wild card 46, something like ABCCoreUI-*

I think no one answered what you asked "FIX your pattern to match any digit at the end of your string, maybe due to behavior of `*` character at last position, output is concatenating 47+42"

You may wrap the regexp in `''` to prevent [Shell Globs](https://yakking.branchable.com/posts/regexps/)

Then, to match zero or more digits

```
sed -r 's/ABCCoreUI-[0-9]*/ABCCoreUI-47/' file.json
sed -r 's/ABCCoreUI-[[:digit:]]*/ABCCoreUI-47/' file.json
```

To match zero or more characters

```
sed -r 's/ABCCoreUI-.*/ABCCoreUI-47/' file.json
```

- `-r` is to enable extended `sed` regexp
- `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` (POSIX) to match a digit
- `[0-9]*` or `[[:digit:]]*` to match zero or more digits
- `.*` to match zero or more characters

Note that `\d` is not working.

Comment: `+` requires extended regular expressions. You'd need an option like `-E` for that. And `\d` is unknown to most `sed` implementations; use `[0-9]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This quick-and-dirty `sed` appears to do the trick:

```
sed '/image.*docker\.xxx\.com.*CoreUI-46/s/CoreUI-46/CoreUI-47/' /path/to/yourfile.json
```

Comment: The OP not only wants to replace `46`, but any number `[0-9]*`

Comment: This was not made clear in the version of the question which I answered.  Better answers have been provided in the interim since the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

In most simple case you can apply the following ***sed*** approach:

```
sed 's/\("image": "[^"]*-\)46"/\147"/g' jsonfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me

`sed "s|\(^.*\"image\": \"docker.abc.com/abc-pr0000abc:\).*|\ABCCoreUI-47\",|g" -i artifactorytest.json`

Comment: (1) I guess you forgot `\1` in the replacement string. (2) `^` is not neccessary if you start with `.*`. (3) If you use single quotes for the script, you don't need to escape all double quotes. (4) We don't know whether the can be matches with other strings than `ABCCoreUI' that should be left alone.